# How do I add space between two images with headers and paragraphs using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I am replicating a portfolio from Codewell for practice and I can't seem to create space between the images without the images stretching and the text disappearing. I've tried using display: flex and justify-content: space-between and it stretches the images instead.

Here is a link to the portfolio for reference: https://www.codewell.cc/challenges/web-developer-portfolio--617d4897a383e41090a3e46f

Here is my code:

```css
.web-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 web-div">
      <img src="Assets/Spense.png" alt="Spense Image">
      <h2>Spence.com <i class="fi fi-rr-arrow-right"></i></h2>
      <p>Rethinking the way writers get paid, an open-source platform designed to help writers focus more on writing, and less when and how they'll get paid. Project in collaboration with Codewell.cc</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 web-div">
      <img src="Assets/YelpCamp.png" alt="Yelp Camp">
      <h2>YelpCamp.com <i class="fi fi-rr-arrow-right"></i></h2>
      <p>Allowing backpack travelers to perfectly plan their trip through an open-source platform similar to TripAdvisor. With over 1m MAU, YelpCamp has been the crowd's favorite in 2021.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using BS5 then you should follow this:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/